# What kind of a wire can we use for frequencies up-to 1Mhz and up?

Tags: wire, high-frequency

I have been reading about [wires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire) in Wikipedia

### What am I doing?

I am reading about wires thinking that I could by my wide knowledge with bunch of reading be capable of creating simple 8-bit or 16-bit CPU

### What I know?

**Proximity effect** and **Skin effect** effect wires, I know how we can produce these, but I don't understand how they actually construct.

### What I want?

I saw many projects on making simple 8-bit CPUs, they use traditional **Stranded wires**, however, I am not sure what is the frequency of that CPU, but let's say I am trying to make 1Mhz CPU, what kind of cables do I need? **Litz wires** seem to be used in >500Khz conditions

Comment: You need to know a lot more than just about wires to construct a CPU. Also physicians treat illnesses; you probably mean physicist. We do not produce the proximity effect or the skin effect; they are the result of the effects of electric fields and obey physical laws.  In some cases, they need to be taken into account in electronic design.

Comment: Consider that in a modern CPU, "wires" are a few **nanometers** apart. Proximity effect isn't that bad.

Comment: @Barry Uh, my fault is that I sometimes rely on text auto-corrections, anyways, I actually know more than wires (if you read my question well), as well as I am reading about CPU architectures, except I can't find a good way to start (other than using the Wikipedia)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are carrying logic-level signals (a few volts and a few milliamps) you can use pretty much anything you want. I've made 20 MHz logic using 30 gauge solid wire - wire-wrap, to be precise, and it worked fine.

What you have to start being careful about are termination and cross-talk.

When running a wire much more than the distance equivalent of your rise and fall times (typically a foot or so) you must consider using twisted pair and termination to avoid signal/power reflections.

When running many signals together, if you bundle the wires  tightly, a transition on one will be radiated and picked up by a neighbor. Separating such wires and making sure they do not run closely in parallel is a good start, but shielding each from its neighbor may be necessary.

As I recall, the generally accepted upper limit on wire-wrap boards, which do use separate wires, is about 100 MHz, although this requires care with terminations.

Comment: some consideration for signal integrity is needed but that is a separate concern w.r.t. what can be used.

Comment: This. The construction of the wire itself is not too important as long as it's small. The routing of the wire itself in relation to other wires and ground planes is critical. Building a CPU out of transistors wired together and trying to achieve 1MHz will probably run into wire length issues first.

Comment: Hm, very interesting, thanks you, I am designing my simple CPU on a breadboard, and thus some cables maybe close enough to worry about radiated/picked up signals (right?), do you know any kind of simple and efficient way to shield the cables? such as using for example cotton wrapping or something?

Comment: @OverCoder If you are talking about a solderless breadboard you will need to learn about good grounding, power distribution, decoupling and a bunch of other things currently beyond your ken. I'd recommend starting your design with the 74HC181 chip. Shielding is _electrical_ shielding, and your idea of cotton means you desperately need to talk to someone who has a clue about this stuff.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast The chip is an ALU, I want to make one, all by myself, anyways I really don't have much knowledge about these stuff, if you think I should talk to someone, then I think my brother knows way beyond that, I will also look about good ground, power distributions, along with others, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know a lot more than just about wires to construct a CPU. Also physicians treat illnesses; you probably mean physicist. We do not produce the proximity effect or the skin effect; they are the result of the effects of electric fields and obey physical laws.  In some cases, they need to be taken into account in electronic design. If you are trying to hand wire a CPU, then you will have a lot more problems than worrying about the hook up wires.  For frequencies near 1 MHz normal stranded or solid copper wire is sufficient as long as the lead lengths are  much less than a wavelength (about 300 meters at 1 MHz). As the frequency increases, you have to start worrying about cable impedance and reflections.  Then you need to use coaxial cable or similar controlled impedance cables. Litz wire is a special type of cable that is rarely used in digital electronics.